# Image won't fully appear

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

Below is the CSS template I am using for my site. I'm just having a problem when I try to add my Logo to my div `#title`, only half the image shows up (height). I think there is a problem with my margins but I can't figure out why the image wont show the full height (width seems ok) no matter how I resize it or change the margin sizes.

Could you suggest solution?

```css
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 99%;
}

body {
    background: $ffffff;
    height: 99%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: center;
}

* {
    font-size: 8pt; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; 
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
}

/* === Containers === */

#mainContentArea {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
    display: table; 
    height: 100%;  
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 600px;
}

.link,.linkActive {
    width:75px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float: left;
    margin-top:24px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background-image:url(tab.gif);
    position:relative; bottom:0px;
}

.link:hover { background-image:url(tab2.gif); }

a { text-decoration:none; }

.link a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#linkGroup {
    margin-right:10px;
    height:40px;
    width:600px;
}

#title {
    width:230px;
    height:40px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}

.contentTitle {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#213E74;
    font-size:19px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:12px;
    margin-bottom:12px;
    width:573px;
}

.pageContent {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    width:560px;
}


#blueBox {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:#E7EDF8;
    width:600px;
    clear:both;
}

#header {
    width:600px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image:url(header.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#footer {
    width:600px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image:url(footer.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
    padding-right:10px;
    color:#BDCDEC;
}

#footer a {
    font-size:9px;
    color:#BDCDEC;
}

#contentBox { margin-top:25px; }

html, body { text-align: center; }

p {text-align: left;}
```

Comment: How big is the image? If its height is larger then 40px your `height` rule will cut it off.

Comment: Even when I set the image to 40px it still is cut off at half, Ive tried editing the height rule aswell and nothing

Comment: This may be a case where we need to see more. Can you post the URL where we can see it in action?

Comment: put it in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What's with this: `background: $ffffff;` ?

Comment: oops lol thanks for noticing that, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `margin-top: 15px;` from `#title` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

remove the

```
   width:230px;
   height:40px;
```

from the css and keep the

```
<img src="image " width="" height=""></img>
```